# Wordpress site flickers and shows old theme after theme css is modified (Firefox only)

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, wordpress-theming

I have a Wordpress site (lastest version) that I host and which is using the Silesia theme. I have installed the Slim Jetpack plugin and used its css editor to modify the look of the site. Now, whenever the site is viewed using Firefox (latest version: 19.02) and any link is clicked, the site flickers, briefly showing the old theme. This only happens on Firefox and not on IE, Chrome, or Safari. Other plugins that are installed include: Subscribe2, Google Analytics, Subscribe2 widget, Manual Control for Jetpack, and WP Super Cache.

It seems as if on Firefox, the site is first rendered using the original theme css and then repainted when it gets to the new css, but according to [How is CSS applied by the browser, and are repaints affected by it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951108/how-is-css-applied-by-the-browser-and-are-repaints-affected-by-it) that's not how it should work.

Does anyone have any idea about what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the problem and it looks like it is a theme specific problem. The original theme css is loaded first, followed by some javascript and then followed by the new custom css. This may cuase the old theme to be visible for a brief moment while the javascript is executing and the browser has not yet had a chance to get to the new css.

I got around this problem by directly modifying the original theme css. Not an ideal solution but it works for now.